# Why is my form not populating my list on my view model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

When I build my form, my list populates correctly. However when I post back to my controller, the list `SynonymTerm` is null.

Here is my view model:

```
public class SynonymEditViewModel
{
    public string Term { get; set; }

    public List<SynonymTermEditViewModel> SynonymTerm;

    public SynonymEditViewModel()
    {
        SynonymTerm = new List<SynonymTermEditViewModel>();
    }
}

public class SynonymTermEditViewModel
{
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public string ReplacementTerm { get; set; }

    public SynonymDuplicateWarning Warning { get; set; }

    public SynonymTermEditViewModel()
    {
        Warning = new SynonymDuplicateWarning();
    }
}

public class SynonymDuplicateWarning
{
    public List<string> Terms { get; set; }

    public SynonymDuplicateWarning()
    {
        Terms = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

A simplified version of the view:

Edit.cshtml

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.Synonyms.SynonymEditViewModel
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Term)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Term)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Term)
    </div>
</div>

<table id="terms-table">
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SynonymTerm)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EditorTemplates/SynonymTermEditViewModel.cshtml

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.Synonyms.SynonymTermEditViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Term)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Term)

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Warning)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the form data pulled from the browser request.

```
Term:Cat
SynonymTerm[0].Term:Feline
```

This data is passed to this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(SynonymEditViewModel synonym)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //breakpoint here
        var dbSynonym = db.Synonym_Replacement_Term.Find(synonym.Term);
        Mapper.Map(synonym, dbSynonym);
        db.SaveChanges(User.Identity.Name, Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(synonym);
}
```

The expected behavior is `SynonymTerm` is a list containing 1 object with `Term="Feline"`, and all other properties having default/constructed values. Is there any reason `SynonymTerm` would be null?

Comment: can you post your controller?

Comment: Posted the controller.

Comment: Post your View, plese.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what happens behind model passing in ASP MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063700/what-happens-behind-model-passing-in-asp-mvc4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In my ViewModel, I needed to add a getter/setter for the list:

```
public List<SynonymTermEditViewModel> SynonymTerm { get; set; }
```

Apparently they're required for the reflection used by MVC, according to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399375/get-set-used-in-viewmodel).